# Multithreading for private chatting between one to one user from public userlist area

Tags: multithreading, chat

I have studied multithreading and its implementation in application especially, chat application. I researched and analysed to implement an one to one private chatting from a public chatting space. It is concerned like clicking a user from user-list by current user, it should popup a frame with connected state of current user who can chat with chosen user. I have been told to use multithreading but i am not getting how to start. Your answers are really appreciated.

Comment: I am assumming java, because rmi tag was already present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to imagine your application and how it will works.
You can have for example, 1 Main Thread for all UI, and one thread per conversation.

The main thread is created at the start of the application, and every time you connect to a user, you open the connection in a new thread (and why not, launch the UI of the chat in a new thread).

But be aware of cross-threading access.

It could be good if you give us more details about what you want  to achieve, why you want to use multi-thread and what technology you will use. With all this informations, you will auto-answer your question.

Best regards,
Sylvain.

Comment: @Sylvain, thank you for your prompt and idea. I want to achieve full-fledge chatting application where users can see public space chatting as well as chatting with specific user. I am using java and RMI technologies. Multithreading is what i have been told to use for good.

Comment: It would be great if you could share me rough coding.

Comment: If you want to see some code using thread in java you can see some tutorial / articles over the web like : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: To be straight, it is like a small portion yahoo messaging or facebook chatting where i can do a private chatting with specific user from the list.